# Firebase auth - How to get auth credential for current user?

Tags: firebase-authentication

In the system I work with, there are multiple web apps and native apps. All of them uses a dedicated web app to authenticate a user. This dedicated auth-web-app invite the user to sign-in and transfer his credential (`credential.toJSON()` as message) to the caller app. Once the credential received, the caller app uses the credential (`OAuthCredential.fromJSON(...)`) to authenticate the user in its own process.

[Here's a video that describe the case.](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8110568/173319818-bd0c532e-f9f2-485f-a20c-5e7bfe606a81.mp4)

After the user has been authenticated once already, this central auth-web-app keeps him authenticated, `auth.currentUser` stays defined in this environment. So when another app opens the auth-web-app, this already has a user in it. And I don't find a way to retrieve or create an AuthCredential from the current user in order to transfer its authentication to the other app.

**Is there a way to get a credential from the current user without asking him to sign in again?**

Comment: If they don't sign in, what makes them the current user? --- In general, I'm having a hard time parsing the explanation. Is there a way you can show a single piece of code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: Really sorry for the hard time. The real simple question is how to get an `OAuthCredential` instance out of the `currentUser`? Here a demo where there's the auth-web-app and another website which calls it to authenticate the user. At the start of the video, there's no `currentUser` in the auth-web-app. After authentication, the `currentUser` stays logged in in the auth-web-app itself. So I wonder how to retrieve a `OAuthCredetial` from it for the next time without calling for `signinWithRedirect`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the question and added a video.